# wireframe not getting displayed for plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a 3D plot using matplotlib for my below code, but in the plot wireframe is not displayed over the surface. I thought it might be a problem with linewidth attribute, so I set it with a larger value but it instead modified surface edge border. I have attached the image.

Is there a way to get the code work as expected and display the wireframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
from matplotlib import cm;
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D;

fig = plt.figure();
axes = Axes3D(fig);#fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d');

axes.plot_surface(stepSizesNormalized,filterOrdersNormalized, mse.T, shade = True, antialiased = False, linewidth = 5, cmap = cm.coolwarm_r);

plt.ylabel('Filter Order');
plt.xlabel('Step Size');
plt.show();
```

[image: 3D surface plot]

Comment: Have you seen if any [example](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d) suits what you want? Maybe try [`plot_trisurf`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo.html).

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `rstride` and `cstride` parameters?

Comment: Supplying some dummy arrays for the x,y,z data omitted in your example, like `x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,10),np.linspace(0,10))`, produces the wireframe for me. Also, in Python it is not necessary to supply the semicolon after each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `antialiased = True`, after changing that, I could see the wireframe.